# Html body content overlapping my footer and header

Tags: javascript, html, css, print-preview

In my Html Report everything working fine, but when i taking print, tables design disturbed between two pages. I also convert it into div structure but same issue occurred, I didn't find solution so far.
Please help.

[Screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTnmv.png)

```
   <div class="madeup-grid-section grid-detail-style" ng-show="nsDivReadyMade">
                            <lable class="grid-heading">Ready Made</lable>
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped page_table table_stylelike_count"
                                   style="border-right:1px solid #000 !important;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="first_row">
                                        <th ng-show="nsSnR">S#</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsItemR">Item</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsPileR">Pile</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsWeftR">Weft</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsGroundR">Ground</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsQualityR">Quality</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsSizeR">Size</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsProcessR">Treatment</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsShadeR">Shade</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsWeightR">Weight</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsQtyR">Quantity</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsPriceR">Price</th>
                                        <th ng-show="nsAmountR">Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="article-items {{item.trbgColor}}" ng-repeat="item in DetailDataList"
                                        ng-if="item.ArticleType=='readymade'" style="border-right:1px solid #000;">
                                        <td colspan="{{ttlRowColspanR+3}}" ng-if="item.RecordType=='ItemDesc'" style="text-align:left !important;">
                                            <span>{{item.ItemDesc}}</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsSnR" rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.GroupNum}}</span></td>
                                        <td rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-show="nsItemR" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.ReadymadeItem}}</span></td>
                                        <td rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-show="nsPileR" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.varPile}}</span></td>
                                        <td rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-show="nsWeftR" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.varWeft}}</span></td>
                                        <td rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-show="nsGroundR" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.varGround}}</span></td>
                                        <td rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-show="nsQualityR" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.Quality}}</span></td>
                                        <td ng-if="item.RecordType!='ItemDesc'" ng-show="nsSizeR" ><span>{{item.varSizeWidth}}<span ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'">*{{item.varSizeLength}}</span> {{item.SizeUnitAbbr}}</span></td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsProcessR" ng-if="item.RecordType!='ItemDesc'">{{item.ProcesName}}</td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsShadeR" ng-if="item.RecordType!='ItemDesc'">{{item.Shadname}}</td>
                                        <td rowspan="{{item.NoOfSubItems}}" ng-show="nsWeightR" ng-if="item.RecordType=='Article'"><span>{{item.Weight}}</span></td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsQtyR" class="numeric-field" ng-if="item.RecordType!='ItemDesc'">{{item.flQty | number:0}} {{item.UnitAbbr}}</td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsPriceR" class="numeric-field" ng-if="item.RecordType!='ItemDesc'"><span>{{item.flPrice | number:2}}</span></td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsAmountR" class="numeric-field"  ng-if="item.RecordType!='ItemDesc'"><span>{{item.CurAbbr}} {{(item.flQty*item.flPrice) | number:0}}</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="footer-row">
                                        <td colspan="{{ttlRowColspanR}}" style="text-align:center;">Total</td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsQtyR" class="numeric-field">{{ttlQtyRM}}</td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsPriceR" class="numeric-field"></td>
                                        <td ng-show="nsAmountR" class="numeric-field">{{CurrAbrr}} {{ttlAmntRM}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Plz upload your code here or give Codepen link.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal complete code is to large, I added code in question.

Comment: It seems issue with PDF, how do you converting this to PDF? you can use jsPDF  for multi-page documents.

Comment: @ShivPatne I just using chrome print preview for pdf download. but it's also happens when we take direct print.

Comment: You should be showing rendered HTML, not AngularJS markup. There may be a substantial difference. We would also need any relevant CSS.